# How to get the data from listview which are not in view?

Tags: android

Hey friends i have use 2 text view now when i fetch data from list view then data which are seen in my phone window are fetched but data which in list view but not view. this data only view when i scroll list but i do not want to scroll and get the all data from list. so please suggest me the solution. and helpers must give some reward point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be done if u can get your text information from adapter by using Adapter

```
myadapter=MyList.getAdapter ;
        View rowview=myadapter.getView(i,null,MyList);
```

now find textview by its id in rowview after that to chewck whether check box is checked or not then u can maintain booleon type array in custom adapter and maintain evrey checkbox state.
    This is complete solution of your problem..

Answer (score 1):

Use `getAdapter()`, get the item's `View` from `findViewById()` and retrieve the data.